# Unity3d build error, postProcessing Player Windows

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build

I have this issue, it's weird.

When I click on Build button in order to make the .apk file, Unity3D starts the process to build the project but in the middle of the build it appears a process called "Postprocessing Player" on a Window and then shows me a window in which I suppose I need to choose a directory but I don't know why or which directory; when I press cancel button appears a text says:

> "Build failure! Unable to locate Android SDK"

[image: Error Image- Unabel to locate Android SDK]

[image: Select Directory Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install android-sdk on your computer !

Link: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other

And here is a tutorial:

http://www.androidcentral.com/installing-android-sdk-windows-mac-and-linux-tutorial

Comment: Hey thank you! your answer is correct! thanks for your time :D

Answer (score 0):

Unity made it easier to locate the Android SDK now.

Go to Edit->Preferences and External Tools

[image]

Click on Download next to Android SDK and JDK, it currently opens to the following websites respectively:

https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: Hey thank you! your answer is correct! thanks for your time :D

Comment: Glad it helped. Looks like @mayo got in first - you should mark him as a right answer.

Comment: I really want to but I have not permission to mark answers, I only have 13 of reputation :(

Comment: As the question asker you always have permission to mark the correct answer.

Comment: whoops I don't know that, my mistake I already marked the Majo answer. Thanks